# How can I remove all trailing whitespace from my excel column?

Tags: excel, whitespace, trim, removing-whitespace, vba

I used the trim function to remove the trailing spaces in column list of names in excel.  However, there are still quite a few names that have additional whitespace after the name that is not removed.

I also tried to create my own:

```
Sub NoSpaces()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        c.Value = Replace(c.Value, Chr(160), Chr(32))
    Next
End Sub
```

However, I get the error:

> Compile Error:
>
> Sub or Function not defined

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: Reflected method change to "Replace" as suggested.**

Comment: In VBA, it's not Substitute, it's [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function)

Comment: I changed the method from Substitute to Replace, however it is still not removing the white space with the edited method above.

Comment: do you know what ASCII value the white space actually is? It could be non-display characters other than chr(160)...

Comment: @xQbert I did not think of that.  Is there a way I can somehow identify what character it is?

Comment: `=code(right(A1,1))`

Comment: that only checks 1 character at a time however... but it's a start  ( i can't think of another way off the cuff  maybe a regular expression to only allow alphanumeric 
 or maybe ..https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/alphanumeric.php

Comment: @tigeravatar, that is assuming that every cell has trailing whitespace

Comment: @obizues Hard to give better suggestions without any sample data.  We're just going off descriptions here.  I'm assuming you can tell which cell has trailing white space that you're trying to get rid of.  Point the formula to that cell to check the code to get the ascii value.

Comment: Maybe.. https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/46253-remove-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string assuming you only want to keep alphanumeric values no special characters or spaces

Comment: Record macro-> highlight whitespace-> ctrl+C-> ctrl+H-> ctrl+V-> leave "Replace with" blank and replace all.  Stop recording, use macro as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was two parts together:

First convert the non-breaking spaces:

```
Sub ConvertNonBreakingSpaces()
Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        c.Value = Replace(c.Value, Chr(160), Chr(32))
    Next
End Sub
```

Then remove all the normal spaces (chr(32)) using the Trim function.

```
Sub ClearSpaces()
Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        c.Value = Trim(c.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```